# Asp Net Core API returns cut off Json

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm learning Net Core and I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.1 to generate the Controllers.

I made these classes:

```
public partial class Posts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Some other atributes

        public virtual ICollection<PostsTags> PostsTags { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Tags
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public List<PostsTags> PostsTags { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PostsTags
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }

        public virtual Tags Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual Posts Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

The fact is that I need this intermediate table because of the many-to-many relation that I'm searching for.

When I run the project, then GET the "Posts" method y obtain this:

```
[{"id":1,"fecha":"2020-09-13T20:07:00","titulo":"Error 1001 al instalar Agilis HTTP Server","ismPostId":3800,"votos":0,"publicadorId":1,"usuarios":{"nombre":"Robert","apellido":"Gotsik","codigo":"rg","password":"rg","id":1,"estado":0},"alcance":0,"texto":"Some explanation here","postsTags":[{"postId":1,"tagId":1,"tags":{"id":1,"nombre":"FICS","postsTags":[
```

The JSON ends cut off.

I have already added the API fluent in OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PostsTags>().HasKey(pt => new { pt.PostId, pt.TagId });
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this issue.

In the ConfigureServices I added this:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(options =>
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

This will ignore the cyclic recursion.